# What sequence should indexes have?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have such sql statement which aggregates data from 3 table of **MySQL** database. The query takes a very long time to complete. I am trying to use index to speed up the process.

```
SELECT
    A.ID_SITE AS OBJECT_ID,
    B.SITE_NAME AS OBJECT_NAME,
    A.POLYGON,
    C.TIME_KEY AS DATE_TIME_KEY,
    B.ADDRESS,
    B.REGION,
    B.DISTRICT,
    B.LOCATION,
    B.LOCATION_TYPE
FROM TABLE_C AS C
INNER JOIN TABLE_A AS A
    ON C.ID_OBJECT = A.ID_SITE
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
    ON A.ID_SITE = B.SITE_ID AND TRACK_IND != 1
WHERE
    (C.TIME_KEY BETWEEN '2018-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-10-31 23:59:59')
AND
    C.ID_TIME_MODE = 3
AND
    C.ID_SUBOBJECT_TYPE = 1
AND (
    C.CONG_POWER >= 1 OR
    C.DIGITAL_POWER >= 3
)
AND
    C.ID_OBJECT NOT IN  (20158, 26875)
AND
    A.MONTH_KEY = '2018-10-01'
```

I need some advice. In what sequence is the best way to create and use index in my case?

What I did right now:

1. `CREATE INDEX index_a ON TABLE_A (ID_SITE);`
2. `CREATE INDEX index_b ON TABLE_B (SITE_ID, TRACK_IND);`
3. `CREATE INDEX index_c ON TABLE_C (TIME_KEY, ID_TIME_MODE, ID_SUBOBJECT_TYPE, CONG_POWER, DIGITAL_POWER, ID_OBJECT)`
4. `CREATE INDEX index_a_month_key ON TABLE_A (MONTH_KEY)`;

Also I think it would be better use `FORCE INDEX` operator, but I am confused how correctly to use them in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your query, the best indexes would probably be:

- `TABLE_C(ID_TIME_MODE, ID_SUBOBJECT_TYPE, TIME_KEY, CONG_POWER, DIGITAL_POWER, ID_OBJECT)`
- `TABLE_A(ID_SITE, MONTH_KEY)`
- `TABLE_B(SITE_ID)`

Comment: I think in index for `TABLE_C` you make mistake. Why you use `C.DIGITAL_POWER >= 3`? Why in index for `TABLE_B` you use only one column? I think there must be `TRACK_IND` column. Also how I can use `FORCE INDEX` operator in my sql statement?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek . . . The `>= 3` was a typo as was the `C.`.  I could swear that I removed them right after I answered.  Oh well.  The only obvious column in `B` not in the `SELECT` is the one in the index.